# Is JPA/JPP/JP3 an android 2.2 ROM?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

Sumsung Kies is offering a firmware upgrade to

PDA:JPA /  PHONE:JPP / CSC:JP3

Is this Android 2.2 or 2.1?

Comment: someone must know what these random letters mean. And shame on you Samsung for using letters which mean nothing to the user and not displaying the version of android which it relates to.

Comment: Have some patience. Not everyone is on the same schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Froyo ROM, according to comments I've read around XDA.

- [A custom Froyo ROM based on JPA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=820414)
- [Blog entry detailing the European Froyo update rollout, references JPA](http://www.samfirmware.com/apps/blog/show/5196562-samsung-starts-froyo-updates-)

Comment: Can you link to any of them?

Comment: Edited answer to include some links.

Answer (score 1):

As Saiboogu says JPx is a 2.2 Froyo ROM, I'm pretty sure the last released 2.1 update was JMx.

For anyone who's struggling to understand Samsung's build numbers, they seem to use a 3 letter code where the first two letters are the software version (going up in alphabetical order) and the third digit refers to a specific customization of that software version, generally network/country specific customizations change the last digit when your operator pre-saves their APN settings, boot logo, and any operator bundled apps directly into the ROM.